# dpkg errors with shared libraries

Tags: kali-linux, upgrade, dpkg

I want to get into infosec. Simple wish right? I don't even want to work in this field, just to know how security and computers work. So I have bought a learning ethical hacking course on udemy from Z security and installed their distro they recommend for learning (this one: https://zsecurity.org/download-custom-kali/). Just after the system install, I run the next commands:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install aptitude
sudo aptitude upgrade
```

but while upgrading I got this error:

```
systemd-machine-id-setup: error while loading shared libraries: libsystemd-shared-244.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
dpkg: error processing package systemd (--configure):
installed systemd package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 127
Setting up samba-common-bin (2:4.12.5+dfsg-3) ...
Checking smb.conf with testparm
testparm: error while loading shared libraries: libaesni-intel.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
dpkg: error processing package samba-common-bin (--configure):
installed samba-common-bin package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 127
Errors were encountered while processing:
systemd
samba-common-bin
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
Setting up systemd (245.6-2) ...
systemd-machine-id-setup: error while loading shared libraries: libsystemd-shared-244.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
dpkg: error processing package systemd (--configure):
installed systemd package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 127
Setting up samba-common-bin (2:4.12.5+dfsg-3) ...
Checking smb.conf with testparm
testparm: error while loading shared libraries: libaesni-intel.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
dpkg: error processing package samba-common-bin (--configure):
installed samba-common-bin package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 127
Errors were encountered while processing:
systemd
samba-common-bin
```

Why am I using `aptitude` instead of good old `apt`? Because with apt I get the same error. I have completely busted the first (and 2nd and 3rd and 4th) system installation so I decided to reinstall everything again and try to upgrade with aptitude. You may say that this is custom distro and you don't need upgrading. Sure I would be satisfied with this, but I get exactly the same errors when installing my GPU drivers for my Nvidia GTX 1050ti card, and I need the drivers for using GPU acceleration in hashcat, without this WPA2 hash cracking may take years (no joke). Btw now apt gives me segfaults no matter what I try to do with it after the upgrade, but at least I have an aptitude.

Alright, AFAIK I can read, so lets see what the error is. It says that I am missing some files: `libaesni-intel.so.0` and `libsystemd-shared-244.so`. Lets try locate them:

```
doggo@Notebook:~$ sudo updatedb
[sudo] password for doggo: 
doggo@Notebook:~$ locate libaesni-intel.so.0
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libaesni-intel.so.0
doggo@Notebook:~$ locate libsystemd-shared-244.so
/usr/lib/systemd/libsystemd-shared-244.so
```

Weird? Yes indeed. I have tried installing some samba packages like `samba-libs` and `libwbclient0` but no changes. Oh have I said that now my `gnome-control-center` isn't working? It requires the `libaesni-intel.so.0` too for some reason.

I tried reconfiguring the dpkg but no luck. Even this: `sudo dpkg --configure -a --force-depends` didn't help.

I have spent about 15-20 hours trying to troubleshoot it with 5 Linux reinstallations! I don't want to change the distro as this one is already preconfigured for the scripts and programs I need to use. Even googling now give only bits of useful info. I need help. Please. How to solve this issues? I could give more experience on my previous installations but let's keep things simple.

Comment: Kali is based on Debian.  Have you looked at these to see if they are relevent to you? https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=917226 https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=945582

Comment: Since Kali is a rolling release, dependency problems and broken installs can happen from time to time.